# handling EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD in Django

Tags: python, django, heroku

I had created an application in Django,for which I had implemented an email service.It was working fine, but now,I have to deploy the application to a server(Heroku).

Now,for configuring email service with django,certain attributes are added in the settings.py file like EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD,EMAIL_BACKEND....

My concern is reagarding the EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD attribute,can this also be deployed?Will there be any security concerns regarding this attribute?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can deploy that variable. Heroku follows the 12-factor application (https://12factor.net) model, which prescribes that these kinds of settings are provided via environment variables (see https://12factor.net/config). In your `settings.py` file (or whatever is appropriate for your framework), you would have something like: `EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD', 'default')`.

You provide the environment variable via the `heroku config:set` command: `heroku config:set EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD=value`. If you have provisioned any database on Heroku, you'll see this with the `DATABASE_URL` variable as well.

The security is a little more nuanced - on the one hand, separating passwords from your source code is invariably a good thing; on the other, you are trusting the provider to secure and isolate your configuration from all others.

You could be truly paranoid, and only provide an encrypted value. But then you have to manage the decryption key, etc., and it gets complicated fast. Overall, my position is that trusting a provider like Heroku is reasonable unless you have very specific security requirements, in which case you should probably consider a different infrastructure/platform provider.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using gmail, outlook emails then make app password from your account that is very useful to access gmail.
https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en

you can save EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD is system environments or any other file and inherit in settings.py of project